# Bounding the probability of at least 2 events (like union bound, except with 2 events)

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $N$ events, each with probability of occurring $p$. What's the best upper bound for Pr[at least 2 of these $N$ events occur]?

For Pr[at least 1 of these $N$ events occur], we can use the union bound to upper bound by $Np$; and this is best we can do since it's possible that the events are disjoint (I guess technically the bound is $\min\{Np, 1\}$).

I think the bound for Pr[at least 2 of these $N$ events occur] should be $Np/2$: we can think of the $N$ events as covering a the full probability space of area 1, with each event covering an area $p$. Then Pr[at least 2 of these $N$ events occur] is the area which is covered by at least 2 events: so we get that 2*Pr[at least 2 of these $N$ events occur] <= $Np$, the total area of the events. This gives the bound $Np/2$.

Is this right? For some reason I can't seem to cleanly formalize this into equations; how would I do that?

EDIT: clarifying the argument, thanks for the answer:

We can think of each event as a region in a space of area 1. The area of each region is $p$. The union bound is just saying that the union of the areas is at most $Np$.

Now the at least 2 case: call the area-$p$ regions "basic regions"

The area we're interested in is exactly the region $S$ of the overall space which is covered by at least 2 of the area-$p$ regions. Say the area of $S$ is $A$.

One way to think of $S$ is that at each point we have a "top layer" basic region and a "bottom layer" basic region (since each point of $S$ is covered by at least 2 regions at each point of $S$). There may be more layers, but we can ignore them.

Now separate the two layers. The total area of the "top layer" region is $A$, the total area of the "bottom layer" region is $A$. But the sum of their areas is at most the sum of the areas of the basic regions (no part of any basic region is double-counted). So $2A \le Np$, and we get the bound.

I am reasonably confident about this argument, but what I said may still be unclear, sorry.

Another attempt: Think of how you could arrange $N$ regions of area $p$ such that you maximize the area covered by at least one region. You want regions entirely disjoint, and you'll get a total area of $Np$. Now suppose you want to maximize the area covered by at least 2 regions: you arrange them so that each covered point has exactly 2 regions covering it; the sum of region areas $Np$ is exactly "double-counted", so our max area is $Np/2$.

Comment: Aren't you considering the case $N=2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now understand your argument and think it is correct. I would express it as follows: Let the random variable $X$ be the number of events that do occur. The expectation of $X$ is $Np$.  You want $P(X\ge 2)$ which, by Markov's inequality, is bounded above by $EX/2 = Np/2$.

A much looser upper bound  is implied by this:  If you call the $N$ events $A_1,\ldots,A_N$ you can consider the $N_2=\binom N 2$ events $B_{ij} = A_i\cap A_j$. You want  an upper bound on $P(\bigcup B_{ij})$, for which the union bound is $N_2 p$.  One also has an inclusion-exclusion (or Bonferroni type) series of over and under approximations: $$P(\bigcup B_{ij}) = \sum P(B_{ij}) - \sum P(B_{ij}B_{kl}) + \sum P(B_{ij}B_{kl}P_{rs}) -\cdots$$
(with upper and lower bounds obtained by truncating the series) but it hard to see that this could be useful.